Redis stack docker UNABLE to persist data
Following is my docker-compose file
services:
  server:
    build:
      context: .
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: ${NODE_ENV}
    ports:
      - "8090:8090"
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
    depends_on:
      - redis-stack  # Ensure Redis starts before the server
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf  # Mount your custom Nginx config
    depends_on:
      - server
  redis-stack:
    image: redis/redis-stack:latest
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
      - "8001:8001"
    command: redis-server --dir /data --requirepass $REDIS_PASSWORD --save 60 1 --appendonly yes
    #    environment:
##      - REDIS_ARGS="--requirepass mypassword"
#      - REDIS_ARGS="--save 20 1"
    volumes:
      - redis_data:/data
volumes:
  redis_data:

I am not  too sure where i am going wrong in this. After I restart the container, the data simply does not persist in my redis insight. I also verified this by interacting with the container and ran redis-cli and tried to get the key
I have verified that my redis_data volume is existent by running docker volume ls.
I also have tried adding
environment:
- REDIS_ARGS="--requirepass mypassword"
- REDIS_ARGS="--save 20 1"
It just simply doesn't work.
Any help would be appreciated, thank you

I HIGHLY doubt it's your issue, but coincidentally I just ran into the same issue. In my case, I had multiple projects each with their own compose file. Each had a redis service named redis (in your case, redis-stack) and some were accidentally marked with restart: always, so I didn't realize they were running. This resulted in my app connecting to tcp://redis but that was actually one of the other project's redis servers which didn't have persistence enabled. So, if you have other compose projects, make sure you aren't running other redis services also named redis-stack.
